# How do I get the remaining dataframe after using np.where in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

What I want (but does not work):

```
df = np.where((df['cd_0'].values == 1) & (df['cd_1'].values == 1), df, np.nan)
```

Note the ***df*** in the second argument of

```
np.where(... , df, ...)
```

I want to get the entire remaining dataframe.

I looked all over stackoverflow for this specific case and the only ones I see, returns a specific data-frame column instead.
This works but only returns a specific column. I want the whole remaining dataframe instead:

Works but not what I want:

```
df = np.where((df['cd_0'].values == 1) & (df['cd_1'].values == 1), df['cd_2'], np.nan)
```

This works exactly how I want it but I dont want to use this method due to speed.

```
df= df[(df['cd_0'].values == 1) & (df['cd_1'].values == 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) from pandas

```
df=df.where((df['cd_0'] == 1) & (df['cd_1'] == 1))
```

Another way is `reindex` back or `.loc`

```
df[(df['cd_0'] == 1) & (df['cd_1'] == 1)].reindex(df.index)

df.loc[~((df['cd_0'] == 1) & (df['cd_1'] == 1)),:]=np.nan
```

Comment: Works but slower than even the method im trying to avoid

Comment: @the_begging_beginner I provided two more methods